# iOS IAP - Receipt ok but nothing on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I released my first iOS app.
There is some in app purchases, a user bought two things on 9th Junuary.

I still can't see anything on the itunesconnect side:

[image]

All the receipts are validated and applied on the server-side.
Here is the response from apple's servers ( https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt ):

```
{
    "status":0, 
    "environment":"Production", 
    "receipt":{..}
}
```

What can explain this issue?

Comment: Is in-app purchase flow successful? There might be possibility of code break? If not then contact apple ( click on help on top right from itunesconnect console and click on contact us )

Comment: I don't think there is problems in my code, because everything works perfectly in sandbox mode, when launching the app with Xcode. 

I will wait some replies, if nothing emerge, then I will contact Apple yes ..